# Select distinct from With Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, common-table-expression

How can I Select distinct [Case Owner], [Case Number] from the following query?

```
WITH RandomCaseNum AS
            (
                    SELECT   [Date/Time Closed]
                            ,[Case Owner] 
                            ,[Case Number]
                            ,ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By [Case Owner] Order By NewId()) Random
                    FROM    [SF].[dbo].[All]
                    WHERE   YEAR([Date/Time Closed]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
                            AND DATEPART(WW, [Date/Time Closed]) = DATEPART(WW, GETDATE()) -1
            )
    SELECT   [Case Owner]
            ,[Case Number]
            ,Random
    FROM    RandomCaseNum
    WHERE   Random <= 5
```

The query above returns:

[image: Duplicated [Case number]]

I want the output result to be like this, without duplicate values of [Case Number]:

[image: Required Output]

Comment: Have you tried either of the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need a GROUP BY, like this:

```
WITH RandomCaseNum AS
        (
                SELECT   [Date/Time Closed]
                        ,[Case Owner] 
                        ,[Case Number]
                        ,ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By [Case Owner] Order By NewId()) Random
                FROM    [RE_INT_IE_SalesForceGoogle].[dbo].[tb_CCAScrubbedAll]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [RE_INT_IE_Darwin].[dbo].[datPREP_02_EmployeeList] E
                        ON [Case Owner] = E.GoogleSalesforceName
                WHERE   YEAR([Date/Time Closed]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
                        AND DATEPART(WW, [Date/Time Closed]) = DATEPART(WW, GETDATE()) -1
        )
SELECT   [Case Owner]
        ,[Case Number]
        ,SUM (Random)
FROM    RandomCaseNum
GROUP BY   [Case Owner]
          ,[Case Number]
HAVING Random SUM (Random) <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do your GROUP BY inside the CTE, not outside of it. Outside, you need to add some meaningless aggregation function to your random number.

It's possible the [Date/Time Closed] in your CTE is probably where the row duplication is coming from. Whether that's the culprit or not, since you're not using it in your outer query, you don't need it in your result set.

```
WITH RandomCaseNum AS
            (
                    SELECT   [Case Owner] 
                            ,[Case Number]
                            ,ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By [Case Owner] Order By NewId()) Random
                    FROM    [SF].[dbo].[All]
                    WHERE   YEAR([Date/Time Closed]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
                            AND DATEPART(WW, [Date/Time Closed]) = DATEPART(WW, GETDATE()) -1
                    GROUP BY [Case Owner] 
                            ,[Case Number]
            )
    SELECT   [Case Owner]
            ,[Case Number]
            ,Random
    FROM    RandomCaseNum
    WHERE   Random <= 5
```